# Understanding push notification environment and pricing in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I understand that a pro account is required to be able to interface to Codename one's push notifications.

1) Is there an incurred fee per push notification, for example a dollar amount per million notifications sent?

2) Does CN1's push notification guarantee delivery? If a phone was offline, would it retry?

3) Is there a guaranteed upper limit latency for receiving a push notification?

4) I was debating using push vs websockets , I am not 100% sure of the trade offs and would appreciate any insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions seem to arise from an approach of using push as a networking protocol which is something Android encourages but it isn't a good idea across platforms.

We would suggest using a proper communication protocol e.g. WebSockets etc. and using push only for marketing related notifications. That is far more portable, powerful and doesn't suffer from the limitations of push (e.g. permissions). Taking that in context the answers below make more sense:

1. No. There are hard quotas: 
   Pro user is limited to 1M per month or 50K per day.
   Enterprise is limited to 10M per month 500k per day. These quotas can be customized on a case by case basis. Notice that these numbers are pretty big for typical apps as long as you don't use push as a networking protocol.
2. No. We use the native push servers and are limited by their delivery limitations, they don't guarantee delivery. Push is inherently unreliable and should only be used as an auxiliary communication medium not as a network protocol.
3. No.
4. Use websockets.

   - Push needs to go thru the Apple/Google servers which are unreliable complex & incompatible
   - Push doesn't work everywhere e.g. kindle or all ports e.g. JavaScript push doesn't work for all browsers
   - Push can be disabled by the user which means you literally can't rely on it working even on supported platforms
   - You need your own servers to handle the push sending and batching anyway so you won't be able to go "serverless" with push
   - Push enforces size limits on messages
   - Push doesn't "really" work when an app is in the background in iOS. In iOS a push notification that includes a visual payload will show that e.g. an icon, badge, message, sound etc. even in a background app. However, the non-visual payload won't be delivered to your app if it isn't running

All things considered push makes sense only for visual notifications and marketing as an addition to your communication protocol not as a replacement.

Comment: Would LocalNotification require pro subscription ? I was just wondering if I will be able to test it out with my current basic subscription. I may end up implementing a hybrid Websockets/ LocalPush comm layer.

Comment: Local notification works since it doesn't need servers but it's a very different thing from push (although it looks similar). On iOS visual push will work in the background and is triggered by a server event. Local notification will need you to schedule the notification